# Should users who vote to close have some experience with the topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

This question [SSRS only displaying first row [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363640/ssrs-only-displaying-first-row) was closed by 5 users, 4 of which appear to be PHP/MySQL experts, because it's "too localized."  The question has 2,726 views and is a common problem among new users of SSRS, which is heavily used in MS SQL Server shops.  I don't think it's too localized, but am not sure if other MS developers would agree or not.  I was going to leave a comment on the question, but it doesn't appear that comments are allowed after a question is closed, so I came here to ask.

Comment: FYI - Comments are allowed after a question is closed.

Comment: I just took a look at more questions on this site.  Apparently comments for IE8 and IE9 users were broken earlier today, but it's fixed now.  Had it worked earlier I would have used it and skipped coming here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first principle of moderation is that extensive knowledge of the subject matter should not be required.  In practice, some domain knowledge is sometimes needed to discern genuine content from flotsam, but there are still many situations where you can moderate without any domain knowledge at all.

That's the case here.  I know very little about SSRS, but it is apparent that the OP made a routine error.  It's not Stack Overflow's job to categorize every possible permutation of every possible error that someone might make with a particular piece of technology.

What we are really after are *principles*.  If the question (and its answer) had demonstrated some sort of troubleshooting principle, it might have been of lasting value to others.  But it doesn't.  It doesn't even explain why "the tablix missing a row group" is significant, or what he did to discover that fact.  Nor does the commenter who said the question helped him explain why.

Accordingly, the question was closed.  Like all closed questions, it is eligible for improvement or deletion.  Improvement seems unlikely, since the OP solved the problem himself, and deletion seems unlikely since the question is otherwise on-topic.

Comment: Great answer, maybe someone should have asked the OP to explain the significance of having a row group, which is different than "too localized."  Flagging is a good suggestion too.  Earlier when I clicked the "add comment" link nothing happened, but now it's open and the comment link works.  I'll have to test it at home, maybe there is something odd happening with my work provided browser (IE9).

Answer (score 4):

Closing does not require knowledge of the specific topics, as some questions don't need specific knowledge to know they are not a good fit for the site.

That being said, it is *hoped* the someone who votes to close does believe that the question truly does not fit in the scope of the site, and isn't guessing or following the herd (i.e. voting for the same reason as other voters).

If you truly believe a post should not be closed, you can flag it for moderator attention and explain why you don't think it should be closed.  If a moderator agrees, the question will get reopened.  Similarly, posting on MSO might attract some experts to the post that can reopen it if they feel it is warranted.

For the record, I'm not an expert but the question and self-answer read very much like a "typo" question (which used to get closed as "Too-Localized" before that close reason was depreciated), so I can understand why it might have been closed.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists, as enforced by the rep requirement to place close votes. Should they have to have some experience with a specific *language*? No, there's no correlation between knowing the specifics of a given language and knowing a question should be closed.

For example, a user who knows Ruby *really* well, should definitely be allowed to close-vote JavaScript questions. This seems really obvious to me. Knowledge of a specific language has very little to do with the quality of questions which deserve close votes. Knowledge of Stack Overflow's Q&A format is infinitely more important, and reflected by the rep requirement.

The question you linked isn't a great defence of your position. Yes, it had 2k+ views, but it's a *two year old question*, and has a whopping 6 upvotes, and one answer which is one sentence long, which is *also* two years old, posted by the question's author. What value would leaving that question open bring to the site? Who cares if it's closed? It's still present, it still shows up in search results exactly as it did before, and the answer is still there. In short, it's exactly as helpful closed as it was open, so who cares?

Comment: Ruby - JavaScript, ok.  PHP - SSRS, not really.  It's not about a specific language, but more of an entire platform.  It's also not about a single question, but the practice in gereral.  If it was open someone could post a better answer, if anyone cared.